# Instance vs. Inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, instance

Im learning c# and have troubles understanding what use cases inheritance has in comparison to instances?

To put it into a context, i am making a console rpg, and my current understanding is that I should make a superclass/baseclass `npc` from which I inherit 3 subclasses `mage`, `paladin` and `thief`, from which i each instance `High level mage`, `low level mage`.

Does it make sense or is there a problem in my logic? Would this also work the other way around with inheritance/instance swapped?

Comment: Why do you need subclasses? A mage is an instance of an NPC. That mage instance can have a level **attribute**

Comment: @OneCricketeer makes sense, what i am trying to achieve is to put inheritance into context and understand its use cases. I am a beginner, so instancing is one of the first things you are being hit with. Now i have troubles understanding why one would use inheritance.

Comment: @OneCricketeer That's one very weird definition. Subclassing types of npc for different abilities and requirements is something quite common. Or are you going to have NPCs that perform magic, sale stuff, use bows, and so on?

Comment: @Rarowcun you would use inheritance if you for example have certain properties that all subclasses have and then some properties that only specific classes have

Comment: Do please use PascalCase for these things; Mage, Paladin, Thief

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> i do not understand use cases of inheritance. Thats what bugged me

You made this comment on another answer; that answer talks about when to identify candidates for inheritance, and OneCricketeer's answer talks about an example inheritance hierarchy but you might still be wondering "what's the point?"

In essence the point is that it allows you to treat things in a common way when you don't care to know the detail about what a thing is. You don't need to know if the thing in your hand is a knife, a spatula, a credit card etc in order to be able to use it to spread mayo on a sandwich; all those things I mentioned could reasonably be used to scoop up mayo and spread it out. They can be treated in a generic way relying on some basic properties that makes them good as spreaders (straight edge, fairly rigid body, water and oil proof)

So lets say you have your character types and they all descend from NPC. Suppose every kind of player has `Health`, and when it hits 0 they're dead. Because all characters have Health, it might make sense to put it on NPC. Maybe different kinds of characters have different starting healths:

```
class Npc{
  public int Health{get;set;}
}

class Medic:Npc{
  Medic(){
    Health = 30;
  }
}

class Soldier:Npc{
  Soldier(){
    Health = 80;
  }
}
```

Suppose your player has organised a clan/posse/team, so your program has e.g.:

```
var team = new Npc[10];
```

You can have up to 10 kinds of character in your team, and it can be any mix. This thing about inheritance is that a Soldier is-a Npc, and a Medic is-a Npc, so now you made an array of Npc, you can stuff soldiers and medics in there:

```
team[0] = new Soldier();
team[1] = new Medic();
```

Suppose someone drops a bomb on the team, it inflicts 55 damage on everyone's health. It'll kill a fresh Medic outright. We don't need to know what kind of player they are; all Npc have Health, and both medics and soldiers can be treated as Npc in this generic "take some Health off them" scenario:

```
void DropBombOn(Npc[] team){
  foreach(var npc in team) {
    npc.Health -= 25;
    if(npc.Health <= 0)
      Console.WriteLine("Character is dead");
  }
}
```

But *which character is dead*? Let's modify the classes:

```
class Npc{
  public int Health{get;set;}
  public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

Set them up:

```
team[0] = new Soldier("john");
team[1] = new Medic("fred");


class Medic:Npc{
  Medic(string name){
    Health = 30;
    Name = name;
  }
}

class Soldier:Npc{
  Soldier(string name){
    Health = 80;
    Name = name;
  }
}


void DropBombOn(Npc[] team){
  foreach(var npc in team) {
    npc.Health -= 55;
    if(npc.Health <= 0)
      Console.WriteLine("Character called " + npc.Name + " is dead");
  }
}
```

You can add another type of character, and they're still also an Npc, so they can be bombed just like all the rest..

Inheritance allows us to treat very specific types as something more general if there are operations that can take place in a general sense, on the general properties that all those kinds of things have.

Maybe all players have a bitmap image within their class that represents them. You can draw the team on screen by visiting each one and saying "give me your pixels"; you don't need to visit each one and say "if this npc is a medic, draw a medic. If this npc is a soldier draw a soldier.." - you just draw whatever pixels they give you and every different player gives different pixels. That, in essence is what we did with name - all characters have a name, we didn't care about which name we got; we just asked and printed out what we got

Another useful thing is that classes can have methods that override (replace) those on the base classes. Here we make a method that describes the character. We put it on the Npc, which means it will be available for anything that inherits from an Npc. We mark it `abstract` which means "anything that inherits from Npc *must* provide a method that returns a string, and is called DescribeYourself":

```
public class Npc{
  public int Health{get;set;}
  public string Name{get;set;}
  public abstract void DescribeYourself();
}


public class Medic:Npc{
  public Medic(string name){
    Health = 30;
    Name = name;
  }

  public override string DescribeYourself(){
    return "I'm a medic called " + Name;
  }

}

public class Soldier:Npc{

  public string ServiceNumber {get; set;}

  public Soldier(string name,string serviceNumber){
    Health = 80;
    Name = name;
    ServiceNumber = serviceNumber;
  }

  public override string DescribeYourself(){
    return "I'm a soldier with service number " + ServiceNumber + " and I ain't telling you anything else";
  }
}


void DropBombOn(Npc[] team){
  foreach(var npc in team) {
    npc.Health -= 55;
    if(npc.Health <= 0)
      Console.WriteLine(npc.DescribeYourself() + " and I'm dead");
  }
}
```

This time we didn't pull the name/print a common message - we asked the npc to describe itself. If it's a Soldier, the soldier version of the code runs and we see *I'm a soldier with service number 12345 and I ain't telling you anything else and I'm dead* in the console. If it's a medic they're a bit more forthcoming with personal info, saying *I'm a medic called John and I'm dead* :)

We also have to provide a service number when we make a Soldier. This outlines that different kinds of classes can have different data requirements/more or less data during setup and use, but we can still treat them in a common way:

```
team[0] = new Soldier("john", "12345");
team[1] = new Medic("fred");
```

The term for this "treat in a common way" is *polymorphism* and it's perhaps one of the most powerful things about C#.. In a practical sense, for example, Microsoft can provide a Stream class that, basically, writes bytes to somewhere, and then loads of inherited classes can write bytes to different places. We now have streams that can write bytes to.. the console, to a file, to some dropbox storage, to memory, to a string... And they're all used in the same way and the person calling write doesn't care how many hoops the code has to jump through to write to console vs file  vs FTP server.. They just call Write with the expectation that the bytes will end up in the place promised.

You can write you own streams, and hand them to Microsoft's classes - Microsoft's classes knew *nothing* about your classes, but you can still ask a Bitmap to Save itself to your stream, and maybe your stream class takes it and adds the bytes to an email and sends it..

Suddenly you just made it possible to have a bitmap write itself to an email and a bitmap can remain completely ignorant of what an email is, but it can still write to it.

You can remain completely ignorant of what a *feeler gauge* is, but you can use it to spread mayo..

Comment: thank you so much for this comment. It really strengthened my understanding of the topic. Your code looks so clean and it makes sense. This comment is coming to my reference notes haha. Thanks again !!!

Comment: You're welcome. I added a bit about methods too - it's not just data that can change according to whether you have a medic or a soldier - you can basically make them do completely different things when you invoke the same named action

Answer (score 2):

Comparing instances to inheritance is akin to comparing apples and oranges. They are more or less unrelated. Inheritance is used to define the heirachy of class definitions, whereas instances are when you create an actual instance of one of those classes.

One (but by far not the only) question you need to ask yourself when considering if inheritance is the right choice is do the subclass and superclass share an **is a** relationship? If the answer is yes, you *might* want to use inheritance. If the answer is maybe or no then you almost certainly don't.

To give you some examples.

q: Does a class `Mercedes` share an *is a* relationship with a class `Car`.
a: Maybe! It's much more likely you just simply have a class `Car` which has a property which is it's `Make` (and `Model` etc).

q: Does a `MyWebPage` share an *is a* relationship with class `BaseWebPage`
a: Probably, yes. This is a common way that inheritance is used. `MyWebPage` overrides some functionality of the base class to control rendering (as one example)

Back to your example. Does class `Mage` Share an *is a* relationship with `Npc`.... answer is another "Maybe". For it to make sense to use inheritance your `Mage` must override some of the base functionality of `Npc` - you might have something like the `Car` example above.

Comment: sounds like a plan, what i should have mentioned is that, as of now, i do not understand use cases of inheritance. Thats what bugged me. You explanation does make sense, but i do not feel like i understood it.

Comment: @Rarowcun I updated with some examples

Comment: yep, your example was top notch. Now I understand it better. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: For the web-page example, a "renderer" class could also be used as an attribute of the `BaseWebPage`, so the answer again should be "maybe"

Comment: @OneCricketeer ha yeah, quite possibly but I was struggling to think of a solid real-world example which I could give a "yes". The choice is pretty much always a "maybe"

Answer (score 1):

**All** classes *inherit*, by default, from `Object`

In order to *use* a non-abstract class (or any inherited ones), you need to create an instance.

Instances hold fields and define functions that can act as wrappers/accessors to other instances stored within that instance (referred to as composition).

---

For the given example, let's say NPC's have levels. All subclasses then extend from that, therefore inheriting the attributes from it. Mages (and other types) have their own properties

```
class NPC {
  int Level { get; set; }
  
  public NPC(int level) {
    Level = level;
  }
}

class Mage : NPC {
  String PrimaryMagic {get; set; }
 
  public Mage(int level, string magic) : base(level) {
    PrimaryMagic = magic;
  } 
}
```

```
var lowMage = new Mage(1, "fire");
var highMage = new Mage(50, "ultima");
```

But you can also make a generic leveled character with no specific attributes

```
var nobody = new NPC(0);
```

You could also do-away with the Mage class and give all NPC's some `Spells` list attribute, for example that defaults to empty/null.

```
var magicStudent = new NPC(1); // starts with no magic
// .. Game progresses
if (magicStudent.Level >= 5) {
  magicStudent.Spells.Add("cure"); // Based on some condition, update a list of spells. 
}
```

Comment: okay, i think i am slowly getting it. But what do you mean with "All classes inherit, by default, from Object"?

Comment: I'd skip that detail for now

Comment: `In order to use a class (or any inherited ones), you need to create an instance`, what about abstract/static classes?

Comment: @Rarowcun For example, `Equals` and `ToString` come from Object class. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?view=net-5.0

Comment: And what about static methods? Lots of functionality is available through static methods that do not require, and cannot use, instances.

Comment: @KalleSvensson What about it. OP didn't ask for that

Comment: Using inheritance to just add new properties is not entirely a good idea.

Comment: @KalleSvensson of course, but OP is talking about classes, not methods.

Comment: @OneCricketeer your example was also very helpful, thanks a lot!!!